# Unable to find Input value using Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

New to python here. I am trying to have my script click a checkbox with a given input value. Unfortunately there is no input ID. Using find_element returns with error:

```
Unable to locate element
```

Using `find_elements()` returns a list and therefore I get the error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

This is the code I have had trouble with.

```
OldJob = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@value='0   ']")
OldJob.click()
```

Here is the html:

[image: Here is the html.]

Any thoughts on how I can get around this?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. Adding picture of code is not good practice no one will write that for you by looking at the image

Comment: You already solved your own problem: You need to iterate the list to find the correct element or you need to use `find_element_by_xpath` with a selector that matches only the wanted element. Without the full html we can not tell if you are using the correct selector.

Comment: The element has a name... have you tried `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='RowNum']")` or `driver.find_element_by_name("RowNum")`?

Answer (score 0):

To locate the `<input>` element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as follows:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='RowNum'][value^='0'][type='checkbox']")
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='RowNum' and contains(@value, '0')][@type='checkbox']")
  ```